# Unable to append a header to a request

Tags: haskell, http-conduit

I need to add a header and send a request:

```
 import Network.HTTP.Conduit
 import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as C8

 --..........
 res <- withManager $ httpLbs $ createReq request
  return ()
    where
      createReq r = r {
        --...........
        requestHeaders = ("content-type", "application/json") : requestHeaders r
      }
```

I've got 2 errors:

```
   Couldn't match type `[Char]'
                  with `case-insensitive-1.0.0.1:Data.CaseInsensitive.CI
                          C8.ByteString'
    Expected type: HeaderName
      Actual type: [Char]
    In the expression: "content-type"
    In the first argument of `(:)', namely
      `("content-type", "application/json")'
    In the `requestHeaders' field of a record


    Couldn't match expected type `C8.ByteString'
                with actual type `[Char]'
    In the expression: "application/json"
    In the first argument of `(:)', namely
      `("content-type", "application/json")'
```

How do I solve them?

**UPDATE**:
`C8.pack` doesn't, it causes other errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error suggests, the compiler expects a type `Data.CaseInsensitive.CI C8.ByteString`, while you provide it with `[Char]` (aka `String`).

I suspect your problem is caused by the missing `OverloadedStrings` extension, which enables arbitrary types to be constructed from string literals. To fix this add the following line in the beginning of your module:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
```

Comment: there must be another way, I'm just curious, what's the way to do the same without OverloadedStrings ?

Comment: Sure. All this extension does is just call [the `fromString` function](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Data-String.html#v:fromString) on literals. IOW, if you want to be explicit, you can just write `fromString "content-type"`.